# Why is add annotations plant the pins one by one instead of using the array and plant it in block?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a coredata which contains coordinates which I use to plant pins on a map.  I use `addAnotations:` using an `NSMutableArray`;  However, `- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation` plants the pins one by one which is very inefficient.

Is there another method that is more efficient?

Comment: do you mean that they are appearing one by one on the map view? Or is just the method iterating the array?

Comment: appearing one by one, which does not make sense.

Comment: That's weird. Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Looping through your pins to place them on the map via `addAnnotations:` is not inefficient. This is exactly how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

If you set in

`(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation`

`customPinView.animatesDrop = NO;` instead of YES.

All the Annotations will load without animation and simultaneously.